# How to enable full screen view of half screen size when runned android app on Motorola Atrix?

Tags: screen-size, motorola-droid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android application built when installed on atrix phone uses only part of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829388/android-application-built-when-installed-on-atrix-phone-uses-only-part-of-screen)

The issue is that the application screen only took up only half of the Atrix's physical screen

I have tried resolving it by adding the codes (shown below) but to no help;

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="960dp"
android:minWidth="540dp"
```

any advise?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when the android:minSdkVersion was set to 3 in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

When I set it to something higher than 3, it used the whole screen. For example:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```